# get query results from a web site in c#

Tags: c#, performance, web

I am using c#. I have imei number of a phone. Need to get details of the phone from http://www.imei.info web site in my c# application.

When I go to the web site and search the imei number of my phone; I see the following URL http://www.imei.info/?imei=356061042215493 with my phone details.

How can I do this in my c# application?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the URL on the run-time and then download the HTML page, parse it and extract the information you want using [HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). See code below as an example and then you can parse returned data to extract your information.

```
private List<HtmlNode> GetPageData(string imei)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        string strPage = webClient.DownloadString(
            string.Format("{0}{1}", WebPage, imei));


        doc.LoadHtml(strPage);
        //Change parsing schema down here
        return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='sortable autostripe']//tbody//tr//td").ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

unless they have an API, you're going to need to read the page details using xml parser like: [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: XML to parse HTML?  Better to use HtmlAgilityPack - HTML is **NOT** XML.

Answer (score 0):

See [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) and HtmlAgilityPack